# Python and JSON - Interact directly with items

Tags: python, json

I'm new to the Bose SoundTouch API.

I need to interact with a command that returns a JSON file constructed like that.

```
{
  "deviceID": "string",
  "source": "string",
  "ContentItem": {
    "source": "string",
    "type": "string",
    "location": "string",
    "sourceAccount": "string",
    "preset": "string",
    "itemName": {
      "text": "string"
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "isNavigate": true,
    "isPresetable": true
  },
  "track": "string",
  "artist": "string",
  "album": "string",
  "stationName": "string",
  "art": {
    "artImageStatus": "string",
    "url": "string"
  },
  "playStatus": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "stationLocation": "string"
}
```

I would like to extract only "source" and "location" in the ContentItem.

```
import json 

with open('test.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data['ContentItem']:
        print('Source: ' + (p['source']))
        varSource = p['source']
        print('Location: ' + p['location'])
        varLocation = p['location']
        print('Type: ' + p['type'])

        print('')

print(varSource)
print(varLocation)
```

Is there a way to complete this more simply ?

Comment: In your example `contentItem` is a `dict` but you treat it as a `list` and we get an index error. As for simplification, that depends on what you want to do with the data. If the goal is just to print it, remove the variable assignments and your good. If you want a list of content/location pairs, that's a different deal.

Comment: Simpler way is to format json, treat it as normal text file, use ```readlines``` and *find* the elements.

Comment: How is working the JSON string directly simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
content = data['ContentItem']
source, location = content['source'], content['location']
```

or

```
source = data['ContentItem']['source']
location = data['ContentItem']['location']
```

or

```
source, location = data['ContentItem']['source'], data['ContentItem']['location']
```

or

```
source, location = (data['ContentItem'][s] for s in ('source', 'location'))
```

or

```
from operator import itemgetter
source, location = itemgetter('source', 'location')(data['ContentItem'])
```